# Javascript test() method syntax error?

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax-error

I'm attempting to convert (what I've found to be) the best email validation function (located here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585?page=0,3) from php to javascript. Regardless of the fact that "you shouldn't validate with javascript because javascript can be disabled". Obviously I can't leave in the checkdnsrr() portion of the function, but everything else should be doable with javascript.

So far the function works as expected up until this line:`else if(/\.\./.test(domain)) {`

I know it's pretty useless without context, so the full function is below. What's also weird is that it gives a "pass" to a line with the exact same regex pattern:`else if(/\.\./.test(local)) {` which is used a few lines before it. Strange.

```
function validEmail(email) {
    var isValid = true;
    var atIndex = email.indexOf("@");
    var ending = email.length - 1;
    if(typeof(atIndex) == "boolean" && !atIndex) {
         isValid = false;
    }
    else {
        var domain = email.substr(atIndex+1);
        var local = email.substr(0, atIndex);
        var localLen = local.length;
        var domainLen = domain.length;
        if(localLen < 1 || localLen > 64) {
            // local part length exceeded
            isValid = false;
        }
        else if(domainLen < 1 || domainLen > 255) {
            // domain part length exceeded
            isValid = false;
        }
        else if(local[0] == '.' || local[localLen-1] == '.') {
            // local part starts or ends with '.'
            isValid = false;
        }
        else if(/\.\./.test(local)) {
            // local part has two consecutive dots
            isValid = false;
        }
        else if(/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/.test(domain) == false)
            // character not valid in domain part
            isValid = false;
        }
        else if(/\.\./.test(domain)) {
            // domain part has two consecutive dots
            isValid = false;
        }
        else if(/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\/$'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/.test(local.replace("\\\\",""))) {
            // character not valid in local part unless
            // local part is quoted
            if(/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/.test(local.replace("\\\\",""))) {
                isValid = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is the error?

Comment: `isValid = "false";`?

Comment: All it says it "SyntaxError: syntax error" in the console.

Comment: That incorrectly rejects IPv6 hosts.

Comment: Ah, yea sorry... That's actually not in the function I'm testing. I had a string there instead which would indicate which portion of the conditionals failed. Forgot to remove the quotes.

Comment: @SLaks all IPv6 hosts or just some random edge case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a `{` in the previous `if`.

Therefore, that `else` has no `if` connected to it.